# How to solve crashed, WebThread (6): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a page which has video player using web view, The error comes while the `webView` load the thumbnail, unfortunately this is only happen on `iOS 10.2`, do you have any idea ?

Below is picture error from xCode

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some code ?

Comment: thanks for the response, but have you see the picture ? @aBilal17

Comment: Yes, but these is not enough information available in picture.

Comment: Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually caused when trying to object at a memory location, when that object has already been released.

While there can be many causes for this the best way to diagnose is to enable Zombies in your XCode.

You need to Edit Scheme and enable Zombie objects in the dialog box.

Now when the app crashes you will get a much better message in the XCode Console to trace the error.

Comment: I've already try to enable zombie object but there are no changes in the error message, it still same @ODev99